# Make certain criteria appear when selection is made?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

User have some options, upon selecting one of them, I want to show more options which will depend on first selected option. Say, user has options to select the number of gates, like 1 or 2. Upon selecting a number I want to show options of all the gates lower than that number. That is,

- if `1` is selected, show options of only `gate 1`.
- if `2` is selected, show options of `gate 2` and `gate 1`.

I have most of the variables within my phpmyadmin for storage purposes to avoid having to create alot of variables in the code. Just want some suggestions and if you see anything I can improve let me know.

```
<div class="form-div-element">
  <label># of Gates</label>
  <select class="gates-change" name="no_gate" required>
    <option value="">Select Gate</option>
    <option value="28">1 Gate</option>
    <option value="29">2 Gates</option>
  </select>
</div>

<?php
  if($result)
  {
  foreach($result as $row)
  {
    if($row->id == 31 || $row->id == 32 || $row->id == 33)
    {?>
      <div class="form-div-element ecl-variation ecl-variation<?php echo $row->id;?>" style="display:block!important">
    <?php }
    else
    {?>
      <div class="form-div-element ecl-variation ecl-variation<?php echo $row->id;?>">
  <?php }?>
      <label><?php echo $row->variation_name;?></label>

      <?php
      if($row->variation_name == 'Stops')
      {?>
        <input type="hidden" name="stopvariationid" value="<?php echo $row->id;?>" id="stopvariationid"/>
      <?php }
      ?>

      <?php
          $var_value = (explode("|",$row->variation_value));
          $var_condition = $row->conditions;
          $arr = array('height_convert_configuration');
          //if($row->special_features != '')
          //{
          //    check_special_function($var_value,$row->special_features,$var_condition);
          //}
          //else if($row->variation_type =='selectbox')
          if($row->variation_type =='selectbox')
          {
            if($row->variation_function == 'calculation')
            {?>
              <select onchange = 'change_variation(this.value,<?php echo $row->id;?>)'>
                <option value="">Select Option</option>
                <?php for($i=0;$i<count($var_value);$i++)
                  {?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $var_value[$i];?>"><?php echo $var_value[$i];?></option>
                  <?php }?>
              </select>
          <?php }
            else
            { ?>
              <select class="gate_datatype" name="gate_type">
                <option value="">Select Option</option>
                <?php for($i=0;$i<count($var_value);$i++)
                  {?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $var_value[$i];?>|<?php echo $row->special_features;?>"><?php echo $var_value[$i];?></option>
                <?php }?>
              </select>
          <?php }
          }
          else if($row->variation_type =='textbox')
          {?>
            <?php for($i=0;$i<count($var_value);$i++)
            {?>
              <?php echo $var_value[$i];?>
            <?php }?>
        <?php }
          else if($row->variation_type =='radiobox')
          {?>
            <?php for($i=0;$i<count($var_value);$i++)
            {?>
              <div class="radiobox-cont">
              <input onchange = 'change_radio_variation(this,this.value,<?php echo $row->id;?>)' type="radio" name="<?php echo $row->class;?>" value='<?php echo $var_value[$i];?>' /><?php echo $var_value[$i];?>
              </div>
            <?php }?>
        <?php }

          else if($row->variation_type =='checkbox')
          {?>
            <?php for($i=0;$i<count($var_value);$i++)
            {?>
              <div class="checkbox-cont <?php echo preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $var_value1[$i]);?>">
                <?php if('Cabin Telephone' == $var_value[$i])
                  {?>
                    <input checked type="checkbox" onchange="change_check_varitaion(this,this.value,<?php echo $row->id;?>)" name="other_option[]" value='<?php echo $var_value[$i];?>' disabled="disabled" /><?php echo $var_value[$i];?>
                  <?php }
                  else
                  {?>
                    <input type="checkbox" onchange="change_check_varitaion(this,this.value,<?php echo $row->id;?>)" name="other_option[]" value='<?php echo $var_value[$i];?>' /><?php echo $var_value[$i];?>
                  <?php }?>
              </div>
            <?php }?>
        <?php }?>
    </div>
  <?php }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make sure you will get appropriate answers. The given code isn't minimal so please consider making all the php parts static so you can create a working snippet. To answer your question the actual content of your condititional options is not relevant. Would be enough to have something like main option, sub1, sub2, sub1.1, sub1.2, sub2.1, sub2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All in all it seems to me that your question actually contains 2 questions:

1. How to dynamically show/hide DOM elements based on user selection

   > Upon selecting a number I want to show options of all the gates lower than that number.
2. How to optimize your PHP code

   > Just want some suggestions and if you see anything I can improve let me know.

*Number two is way to broad!* Maybe just one quick suggestion: If it works then its fine. Overlooked it fast and seems to be ok.

**See my working snippet for number one**, which actually only needs a little customization of your existing source code (if any at all). Don't forget its just a mockup; if you need some further help or want some deeper explanations about whats going on then let me know...

```js
jQuery('.form-div-element').not('.ecl-variation').find('select').on('change', function() {

    var i = -1,
        $conditional = jQuery('.ecl-variation').hide(), // hide in advance
        iGates = +(jQuery(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-gates-sum')); // get required gate(s) based on selected options "data-gates-sum"-attribute
        // version based on text: `iGates = +($(this).find('option:selected').text().split(' ')[0])` | pro: no additional markup, con: error prone, maintenance

    // count up to required gate(s) and make them visible
    while ( ++i < iGates ) {
        $conditional[i].style.display = 'block';
    }

});
```

```css
.ecl-variation{
    display: none; /* hide conditional selects in advance */
}
```

```html
<!-- minimized mockup -->
<div class="form-div-element">
    <label># of Gates</label>
    <select>
        <option value="">Select Gate</option>
        <!-- decided to add a data attribute instead of relying on text which could change more likely (maintenance) -->
        <option value="28" data-gates-sum="1">1 Gate</option>
        <option value="29" data-gates-sum="2">2 Gates</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-div-element ecl-variation">
    <label># of Gates | conditial 1</label>
    <select>
        <option value="">Select Gate Sub</option>
        <option value="3">abc</option>
        <option value="4">xyz</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-div-element ecl-variation">
    <label># of Gates | conditial 2</label>
    <select>
        <option value="">Select Gate Sub</option>
        <option value="5">123</option>
        <option value="6">789</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### How to implement?

```css
.ecl-variation{
    display: none; /* hide conditional selects in advance */
}
```

```html
<body>

    <!-- minimized mockup -->
    <div class="form-div-element">
        <label># of Gates</label>
        <select>
            <option value="">Select Gate</option>
            <option value="28" data-gates-sum="1">1 Gate</option>
            <option value="29" data-gates-sum="2">2 Gates</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-div-element ecl-variation">
        <label># of Gates | conditial 1</label>
        <select>
            <option value="">Select Gate Sub</option>
            <option value="3">abc</option>
            <option value="4">xyz</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-div-element ecl-variation">
        <label># of Gates | conditial 2</label>
        <select>
            <option value="">Select Gate Sub</option>
            <option value="5">123</option>
            <option value="6">789</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <!-- YOUR CODE ENDS HERE -->

    <!-- load jquery from cdn -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- provide a local copy as fallback in case that cdn is not available  -->
    <script>window.jQuery||document.write('<script src="path/to/your/local/copy/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    <!-- implement your custom site specific script(s) inline -->
    <script>
    (function( $ ) {

        $('.form-div-element').not('.ecl-variation').find('select').on('change', function() {

            var i = -1,
                $conditional = $('.ecl-variation').hide(),
                iGates = +($(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-gates-sum'));

            while ( ++i < iGates ) {
                $conditional[i].style.display = 'block';
            }

        });

    })( jQuery )
    </script>

    <!-- instead of deploying your scripts inline you can load them also like this:
    <script src="path/to/your/app.js"></script>
    -->

</body><!-- make sure that your scripts are located just before the closing body tag -->
```

Comment: I am not a big javascript user how can I implement javascript into my php and html code. I see you are using script src which leads me to believe it is similar to how you would embed an image. Just need clarification on that please and thank you

Comment: Jepp you are right. I updated my answer accordinngly: please see snippet below "How to implement?". I deleted all the known comments and added new ones concerning the actual implementation. Hope it helps @harrisdd

Comment: I wanted to ask really quick would I just have to put my code where you say "<!-- implement your custom site specific script(s) inline -->"

Comment: No the code is just html and php code your addition is the js in the code I put all my code in my description

Comment: You wrote: "I just have to put my code where you say ..." then what do you mean with your code? Sry

Comment: Sorry I meant I don't have any other additional JS code, it was all html css and php. I wanted to see where can I place that code within my code I have written to make sure it all flows without changing much in my code. Thank you

Comment: Jepp. Everything fine my friend. I updated the implementation snippet. See "YOUR CODE ENDS HERE". After that line just copy and paste the source code the way I showed - right before the closing body tag. Regards :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two ways first way is to do ajax and second way is using css.
First method suppose this is your select code where you can select gate

```
<div class="form-div-element">
  <label># of Gates</label>
  <select id="gates" onchange="change()" class="gates-change" name="no_gate" required>
    <option value="">Select Gate</option>
    <option value="28">1 Gate</option>
    <option value="29">2 Gates</option>
  </select>
</div>

// and this is your sub gates options which will be empty at first and its display will be none

<div id="subgates_div" class="form-div-element" style="display:none;">
  <label># of Sub Gates</label>
  <select id="subgates" class="gates-change" name="sub_no_gate" required>
    <option value="">Select Sub Gate</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

on selecting gate what you can do is use ajax to get the sub options of the selected gate like this. in this code your url and my url will be different.

```
function change() {

    var selected = $('#gates').find(":selected").attr("value");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<?php echo base_url('get_sub_options') ?>',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {category: selected},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            //remove disabled from province and change the options
            $('#subgates_div').show();

            $('select[name="sub_no_gate"]').html(data.subgates);
        }
    });



}
```

and your php function should be like this here first i have made an array named subgates. and i have retrieved subgates from database using the value from post. this query might be different in your case. the i have applied foreach loop for sub gates and created a new option element with respective subgate id and subgate name and appended it to array. and at last the array is returned using json_encode

```
function get_sub_category() {
    $data['subgates'] = array();
    $subgates = $this->db->get_where('subcategories', array('id' => $_POST['category']))->result();
    foreach ($subgates as $key => $val) {
        $data['subgates'][] = <<<EOD
        <option value='$val->id'>$val->sub_gate_name</option>
        EOD;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

and the other method is using css. to do this you should list all this options of gate and subgates at first. like this

```
// gates options
<div class="form-div-element">
  <label># of Gates</label>
  <select id="gates" onchange="change()" class="gates-change" name="no_gate" required>
    <option value="">Select Gate</option>
    <option value="28">1 Gate</option>
    <option value="29">2 Gates</option>
  </select>
</div>

//sub gate options one
<div id="subgates-<?php echo $subgates->id; ?>" class="form-div-element" style="display:none;">
  <label># of Sub Gates</label>
  <select id="subgates" class="gates-change" name="sub_no_gate" required>
    <option value="">Select Sub Gate</option>
  </select>
</div>

//sub gate option 2
<div id="subgates-<?php echo $subgates->id; ?>" class="form-div-element" style="display:none;">
  <label># of Sub Gates</label>
  <select id="subgates" class="gates-change" name="sub_no_gate" required>
    <option value="">Select Sub Gate</option>
  </select>
</div>
// and so on
```

In this case what you should remember is that your sub gates option div id should be dynamic and display will be none at first
now when you select a gate use onchange and change the display css of respective sub gates like this

```
function change() {

    $(".form-div-element").hide();
    var selected = $('#gates').find(":selected").attr("value");
     $('#subgates-'+selected).show();




}
```

hope this will give you some idea and if you have any confusion feel free to ask

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions but it's not exactly what I was asking for. Attached I have my my data table in my phpmyadmin I set up. In the code I have them all called at once. So even if the user selects # of gates to be 1 gate, they would see gate 2 options such as gate 2 material etc. I am trying to figure out if I can only do this with an if-else statement or maybe another tactic to do this.